# error launching gvim build from sources

Tags: vim

I've build vim 7.3 from sources. But, if i try to launch vim -g (or gvim), I am getting error 
E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time'
These are the changes i did to the Makefile:

```
CONF_OPT_PERL = --enable-perlinterp=dynamic
CONF_OPT_PYTHON = --enable-pythoninterp
CONF_OPT_PYTHON3 = --enable-python3interp
CONF_OPT_CSCOPE = --enable-cscope
CONF_OPT_ACL = --disable-acl
CONF_OPT_GPM = --disable-gpm
CONF_OPT_SYSMOUSE = --disable-sysmouse
CONF_OPT_FEAT = --with-features=normal
prefix = $(HOME)
```

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure you're picking up the correct vim ? e.g. are you specifying an explicit path ? Does 'which vim' tell you the expected vim ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the corresponding GUI libraries installed. Then, `./configure` should be able to detect them and issue positive messages.

There are a lot of posts about compiling Vim and installing dependencies for your distribution out there; go search for one.